# SQL INSERT code PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have been very confused on what is wrong with this php code, it only gives me blank pages.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mosys`.`allcheck` 
(`cDate`, 
    `cCheckNo`, 
        `cClass`, 
            `cPayee`, 
                `cPayeeAddress`, 
                    `cSender`,
                        `cSenderAddress`, 
                            `cAmount`) 
VALUES (".getDateTime()."', 
        '$_POST[cCheckNo]', 
            '$_POST[cClass]', 
                '$_POST[cPayee]', 
                    '$_GET[cPayeeAddress]',
                        '$_POST[cSender]', 
                            '$_POST[cSenderAddress]', 
                                '$_POST[cAmount]');";

}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
```

What seems to be wrong?

here is the layout [link](http://pastebin.com/yeFQPhjJ)
and the php [link](http://pastebin.com/mSFTTdHz)

Comment: `insert` doesn't return anything.

Comment: What should it be outputting? It'll only print something if the query fails. Do you mean that it's not inserting anything, and you're not getting an error?

Comment: Do not forget SQL injection7

Comment: @andrewsi its not inserting anything on the database and also not showing error

Comment: @ElyBesiño - what is the error in die

Comment: @EdHeal no error shown, just a white page

Comment: View source? Write the output of die before hand to the page

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP Code is just one output declared: die();
So when there is no error, i think your code works well. Why are you expecting something else then a blank page?

Comment: if there is no error then it should insert something, but it does not insert anything and show no error

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mosys.allcheck 
(cDate, 
    cCheckNo, 
        cClass, 
            cPayee, 
                cPayeeAddress, 
                    cSender,
                        cSenderAddress, 
                            cAmount) 
VALUES ('".getDateTime()."', 
        '".$_POST[cCheckNo]."', 
            '".$_POST[cClass]."', 
               '".$_POST[cPayee]."', 
                    '".$_GET[cPayeeAddress]."', 
                        '".$_POST[cSender]."', 
                            '".$_POST[cSenderAddress]."', 
                                '".$_POST[cAmount]."')";

}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the table name you want to insert in ?

Comment: table name is allcheck with cCheckNo as primary

Comment: here is the layout [link](http://pastebin.com/yeFQPhjJ)
and the php [link](http://pastebin.com/mSFTTdHz)